# C++ Print one letter at the time. How to?

Tags: c++, windows, sleep

Let's say i have a string, that contains a message. If i want to print it on the screen, i just can do `cout<<string, or cout<<"Hello!"`. But the message gets printed all at once.

So what i am looking for is a function that takes a message and a number as input variables, and prints the message one letter at the time, using the number as delayer.

Like this:

`void slow_print("Hello!", 5);` This means print each letter with 5 seconds of delay between them.

Unfortunately, i have no idea how to do that (except for the delay, wich you can do with the Sleep() function), and so i came up with this ugly looking solution:

```
string A = "A", B = "B", C = "C", D = "D", E = "E" .... //etcetera...
```

Then i would declare a vector, wich contains those letters. So then i could do a for loop, for instance, that prints one vector cell at the time.

```
vect[dimension] = { H,e,l,l,o,_,h,o,w,_,a,r,e,_,y,o,u }

        for (int i = 0; i<dimension; i++)
    { 
      cout<<vect[dimension];
      Sleep(delay_time);
    }
```

This is the only solution i have found. It works but, it is very uncomfortable to use.

Does anyone have a better idea? 
I hope the community can help me :)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can index into a `std::string` in much the same way...

Comment: You do know that you can index a string and get a single character at a time out of it?

Comment: You should put a `cout.flush();` after `cout<<vect[dimension];`  to ensure the character is actually printed. Also use a `std::string` as mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually index the individual characters of a `std::string`.
Your function could look like this:

```
void slow_print(const std::string& str, int delay_time) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i != str.size(); ++i) { 
        std::cout << str[i];
        Sleep(delay_time);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

```
unsigned long k;
std::string str="Hello"
for (k=0;k<str.size();++k) {
    std::cout << str[k]; Sleep(5);
}
```

You are able to index a string. If `str` is equal to `"Hello"`, `str[0]`, for example, will be equal to `'H'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use c++11 or later...

```
std::string str("hello.");
std::for_each(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char c){
    std::cout << c;
    Sleep(1000);
});
```

`std::for_each` comes from <algorithm>.

Comment: Sleep( ) isn't a "C++11" thing, it's a Windows function.

Comment: @AchillesRasquinha, it isn't a "C++11" thing, but it is a thing in the question.